# contour graph tuple index out of range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the *contour* function of *matplotlib.pyplot*. I get an error *tuple index out of range*.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
x, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=10)
y = y + abs(y/2)
thetaInitial = np.random.randn(3,1)
thetaFinal   = np.random.randn(3,1)

def f(x): return x**2+x

xmesh, ymesh = np.meshgrid(x, y)
print("x :", xmesh.shape); print("y :", ymesh.shape); print("z: ", z.shape)
z = f(np.array([xmesh, ymesh]))
plt.contour(X=xmesh, Y=ymesh, Z= z, levels=20)
```

­

```
tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that need to be addressed:

1. Please, read the documentation to obtain contour plots with `help(plt.contour).
2. from the docs, you'll see that `x, y` needs to be monotonically sorted. You can achieve that with `np.sort(x.reshape(len(x)))`.
3. You evaluated your function with `z = f(np.array([xmesh, ymesh]))`, obtaining an array with shape `(2, 100, 100)`. From the docs, `Z` must be a 2D array. So you have to execute `plt.contour(X=xmesh, Y=ymesh, Z=z[0])` or `z[1]`.

Comment: I was receiving the original error using `plt.contourf()`, and for those curious, you cannot use the named arguments e.g., `X=, Y=`. Just do e.g., `plt.contourf(xmesh, ymesh, z[0])`